# How to add a new alternative constructor in Java?

Tags: java, python, constructor

Below is a `Circle` class in python,

```
class Circle(object):

   def __init__(self, radius):
      self.radius = radius
```

that gets redesigned as shown below, based on customer requirement change,

```
class Circle(object):

   def __init__(self, radius):
      self.radius = radius

   @classmethod                # Alternative constructor  
   def from_bbd(cls, bbd):     # Bounding box diagnol
      radius = bbd / 2.0 / math.sqrt(2.0)
      return cls(radius)
```

---

`Circle` class provide a contract to get sub-classed.

In class design life-cycle, What is Java's approach in adding a new alternative constructor, in above scenario?

Comment: Show us what you've created in Java, first.

Answer (score 1):

You would either add an alternative constructor with the new signature, or, in a similar fashion than that of your `from_bbd` classmethod, use a factory method to build a circle from a bounding box.